# JavaScript Smart Xpath to element not working in java-script on CefSharp win form

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am trying to xpath to element in java script but it not working when xpath is advance or smart

i am using following code for xpath to element

Open google.com and test this code

```
function XpathtoElements(STR_XPATH ) {
    var xresult = document.evaluate(STR_XPATH, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    var xnodes = [];
    var xres;
    while (xres = xresult.iterateNext()) { xnodes.push(xres); }
    return xnodes;
}

var xpath = '//img[not(contains(@src,"/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"))]';

var l = XpathtoElements(xpath);
```

Not found any element but, this xpath working on google chrome xpath to find

Not working on cefSharp browser in win form

[image: Screenshot about issue]

Comment: It would be good to add a small example of the document content, and provide the expected output you would get for it. It seems to work fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/e60hp75f/).

Comment: Possibly your code runs before the elements are dynamically added to the document. But without a reproducible example, we cannot know.

Comment: What version of `CefSharp` are you using and which version of `Chrome` did you compare it to? If they're not at least the same major version then it's not a particularly meaningful test

Comment: @amaitland I am using Chromium 75.0.3770.100. CEF r75.1.14+gc8116e+ Chromium 75.0.3770.100. CefSharp 75.1.141.0 64Bit

Comment: What version is what exactly? Please review your comment.

Comment: 75.1.141 this version of  winform of cefSharp @amaitland